# Can I use a resistor for overcurrent protection?

Tags: resistors

I have a circuit that draws ~350 mA and uses 6v. Can I put a 5watt 15 ohm resistor in series to prevent overcurrent, (I don’t want the current to go over 400 mA in case of a short circuit). Here’s my math:
I = 6v / 15
I = 0.4 A

Comment: This is like trying to set a maximum speed limit to your car by always holding the brake down a fixed amount at all times.

Comment: Hint: Yes, but the value must be very small. You'll need to find a way to amplify that value and make a decision based on that.

Comment: Use a fuse or explain how the "over 400 mA" might be damaging.

Comment: Hmmm I would use a fuse, but I was worried cause I couldn’t find many for lower currents. I want to turn on a commodore minuteman 2 but was worried the old recharable batteries would be bad so I thought a would wire the power with my own battery, but wanted some overcurrent protection in case the calculator is shorted somehow.

Comment: @DKNguyen Yeah that’s what I was hoping for:D But it seems that there is voltage drop across resistors?

Comment: @NO_GUI You're missing that in both cases it doesn't limit as much as it decreases everything across the board, all the time.

Comment: @DKNguyen How does it do that? (I’m pretty new to resistors :D)

Comment: The resistor is always there doing its thing, not only when your current has exceeded your desired maximum limit.

Comment: @DKNguyen I think I’m understanding now, so the calculator must have resistance to only draw 350 miliamps so the resistance of the calculator plus my resistor would stop the current even further?

Comment: Yes, all of the time.

Comment: @DKNguyen Ok thank you for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this won't work since it will disrupt normal operation of the circuit. If the circuit draws the expected 350mA current, the voltage dropped across the resistor will be 5.25 V, so the circuit will only be running on 0.75 V, not 6 V.

Comment: Oh I didn’t know about that! How does voltage drop across resistors work?

Comment: It's just Ohm's Law, the same principle you used in your original calculation. It can be expressed as \$V=IR\$, \$R=\frac{V}{I}\$, or \$I=\frac{V}{R}\$. Your original current limiting idea used this -- the fact that the resistor will drop the full 6V at 400 mA, using 6V = 400mA * 15 mA, and a circuit with only 0V cannot draw any current (normally).

Comment: Oh cool! Can you show me how you got 5.25?

Comment: It's \$V=I\times R=350\text{ mA}\times 15\text{ }\Omega = 5250\text{ mV} = 5.25\text{ V}\$. If you have trouble with units you can type `350mA * 15 ohms` into Google and it converts it for you.

Comment: Oh I always thought the equation meant you would need 5.25v to get 350mA with 15 ohms resistance, is that right?

Comment: @NO_GUI - Well, that's right assuming your circuit is just a resistor. In that case the voltage drop and the supply voltage are the same because of how their connected.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you! Is there any good articles or books I should check out for overcurrent protection, or more on resistors?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with what books are best. You basically just want an introduction to electronics -- they typically cover resistors circuit analysis thoroughly. Perhaps you could go through this free class: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-002-circuits-and-electronics-spring-2007/

Comment: Thanks I’ll check that out!